# Different bus representations on schematics?

Tags: schematics, bus

Here is an excerpt from a sample "data flow" diagram:

[image]

Now both lines in both circles represent buses but in #2, there is no bus arrow that goes to the IC.

What is the difference between them? Does #2 means that this IC never reads from that bus but only outputs to it, whereas #1 means this IC both reads from and writes to this bus?

If that's the case, what about if we wanted to represent: "This IC only reads from that bus but never outputs to it." How would we represent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 2 is an output bus and number 1 is an input bus - look at the device in between these buses - it's a data buffer - data goes in one end and comes out the other.

> If that's the case, what about if we wanted to represent: "This IC
>   only reads from that bus but never outputs to it." How would we
>   represent that?

There will just be a bus with an arrow pointing into the chip.

Comment: So the IC uses bus #2 only to write to and bus #1 only to read from?

Comment: Correct, the chip buffers data in and produces outputs on the right hand side.

Comment: But what if we wanted to represent: "This device both reads from and writes to this bus." Is it the same as representing: "This bus only reads from this bus."? Is there a difference between these representations?

Comment: If you have a device that can read from and rewrite back to the same bus then a different symbol is used - it's up to the designer how they show this symbol and some designers won't bother with a bidirectional symbol but I think it's a good idea - you can draw a little two-way arrow inside the rectangular bus shape to imply this. There are no hard and fast laws that govern what a designer should do.

Comment: @Utku: The distinction between input and output is most important in circuit design approaches where every signal is always driven by exactly one source, which is the case in many modern designs since any time a new device starts outputting on the bus is likely to result in bus contention unless the it waits until some time after the old device has released the bus.  Using separate devices for each data source eliminates such issues, but it greatly amplifies the distinction between inputs and outputs.